# For model selection, using n-fold cross-validation, should performance be averaged over the folds or calculated based on all predictions?

Tags: cross-validation, svm, model-selection, libsvm

In $n$-fold inner-cross-validation, for model selection, should performance be calculated $n$ times and then averaged, or should all predictions be made covering the whole training set, and then performance calculated $1$ time?

For example, in $5$-fold cross-validation, there is $5$ validations tests (each time being $4/5$ segments [i.e ~$80$%] training, and $1/5$ [i.e. ~$20$%] validation testing). In which case, should performance be averaged by calculating performance metrics $5$ times, or $1$ time at the end of the procedure?

This is for model selection only (not the final model, and not outer-cross-validation for generalised performance).